# ELKI: clustering object with Gaussian uncertainty

Tags: gaussian, elki

I am very new to java and using ELKI. I have three dimensional objects have information about their uncertainty ( a multivariate gaussian). I would like to use FDBSCAN to cluster my data. I am wondering if it is possible to do this in ELKI using the `UncertainiObject` class. However, I am not sure how to do this.

Any help or pointers to examples will be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use, e.g., `SimpleGaussianContinuousUncertainObject` to model uncertain data with Gaussian uncertainty. But if you want a full multivariate Gaussian, you will have to modify its source code. It is not a very complicated class.

Many of the algorithms assume you can put a bounding box around uncertain objects, in order to prune the search space (otherwise, you will always be in O(n^2)). This is more difficult with rotated Gaussians!

The key difficulty with using all of these is actually data input. There is no *standard file format* for specifying objects with uncertainty. Apparently, most people that work with uncertain data just use certain data, and add an artificial uncertainty to it. But even that needs a *lot* of parameters to tune, and I am not convinced by this approach.